# Does grep work differently on OSX

Tags: regex, macos, bash, grep

I am trying to use grep like I am used to from Linux, with all its amazing features and all the power from RegEx,... but on Mac OS X  it's not working as I expect.

If I use "-P" (Perl Regex) it gives me the "usage" (--help) output.
In there we find the "-P" parameter in the list of parameters "-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZ"...
Still not working.

Another example is the asterisk or the plus sign.
I am trying this http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/conffile

To check a config file for inappropriate content that instruction uses:

```
if egrep -q -v '^#|^[^ ]*=[^;]*' "$configfile"; then
  echo "Config file is unclean, cleaning it..." >&2
  # filter the original to a new file
  egrep '^#|^[^ ]*=[^;&]*'  "$configfile" > "$configfile_secured"
  configfile="$configfile_secured"
fi
```

And it does not work on lines like this:

```
DATABASE=some_database; ls -la
```

What am I doing wrong?
Cause all of this works just fine on Linux machines.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an under-informed rant.

Comment: The version of grep included with 10.8 does not support `-P`. `grep -V` returns `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` in 10.8 and `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1` in 10.7. You can install a newer version of GNU grep with `brew tap homebrew/dupes; brew install homebrew/dupes/grep`

Comment: Not really fair, Jonathan. I should have choosen my language better, but question still remains.
I am asking questions to GET informed, so it is clear, that I am at point of asking the question "under-informed".
I got great answers though.
Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 10):

ubuntu (well, my ancient ubuntu 8 box I'm sitting beside…):

```
$ grep -V
GNU grep 2.5.3
```

OS X:

```
$ grep -V
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```

Yeah; they're different programs. OS X is not Linux. It's based on BSD.

If you want the GNU version of grep, with its various extensions, you can install it easily with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).

Comment: Installed it with Homebrew but `grep -V` still prints `FreeBSD`.

Comment: You have to use `ggrep`.

Comment: you could also create alias for your ggrep so it is used instead of the system one.

Answer (score 10):

On OS X you have FreeBSD `grep` by default, on Linux usually GNU `grep`.

The following resources may explain why GNU grep seems to be better (and faster):

- [why GNU grep is fast (by GNU grep's original author)](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html)
- [BSD grep on the FreeBSD Wiki](https://wiki.freebsd.org/BSDgrep)
- [GNU grep is 10x faster than Mac grep](http://jlebar.com/2012/11/28/GNU_grep_is_10x_faster_than_Mac_grep.html)

Answer (score 4):

Mac OS X is based on BSD, and does not use the GNU tools you are used to. I'd read up on [POSIX grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) because without GNU extensions you'll keep getting agitated for no reason. Everything should still be possible, just not in the exact way you're used to.

Comment: Thanks.
But do you have an explanation for the not matching part of my question? The paragraph about extend regular expressions (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04) saying it can lead to undefined results for characters like "*" and "+" does not seem to apply here.
So why am I getting no result?

Comment: @func0der sorry I don't speak regex `;-)`. The quickest solution for you is to just install GNU grep, either from source or via homebrew/macports/...

Comment: Yeah, but I am not writing those scripts for myself, but for co-workers who use out of the box osx.
Thanks for your answer anyway :)