# List public IP addresses of EC2 instances

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, jq

I want to list the public IP addresses of my EC2 instances using Bash, separated by a delimiter (space or a new-line).

I tried to pipe the output to [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) with `aws ec2 describe-instances | jq`, but can't seem to isolate just the IP addresses.

Can this be done by `aws` alone, specifying arguments to `jq`, or something else entirely?

Comment: Did you try: `curl --silent http://ipecho.net/plain`

Comment: Or `curl icanhazip.com`, or `curl ident.me`

Comment: This shows me my own IP address.. not a list of those my instances have

Comment: If the output of `aws ec2 describe-instance` has the info you want, then you'll have to show some sample output of that command to get general help since most people won't have `aws` installed.

Comment: For those who came here looking to get the IP via a script running **on the instance**, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46323720/117471

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Directly from the [aws cli](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress" \
  --output=text
```

Comment: Awesome. But this outputs three columns: one with IP's on every row and two with IP's only on some rows. I get a nice  tab-separated list when I use `Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress[]` for the query argument instead.

Comment: Wrap your `PublicIpAddress` in square-brackets to ensure 1-per-line, as suggested here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/914#issuecomment-56210312. This works for me `--query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[PublicIpAddress]`

Comment: Is there a way to filter using security group? I tried: "aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=vpc-id,Values={vpcid} Name=InstanceId,Values={securityGroupID} --output=text"  . But I get nothing

Comment: If you want the instances' KeyName to go with the public IP address, you can get it with `--query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[KeyName, PublicIpAddress]"`

Answer (score 21):

- Filter on running instances (you can drop that part if you don't need it)
- Query for each PublicIPaddress and the Name Tag, handling when Name isn't set

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --filter "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
  --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PublicIpAddress, Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value|[0]]" \
  --output text
```

Comment: aws ec2 describe-instances --region {{ region }} \
      --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running \
      --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[].{ID:InstanceId, Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value,EnvID:Tags[?Key==`EnvID`].Value, EnvLayer:Tags[?Key==`EnvLayer`].Value, Type:InstanceType, AZ:Placement.AvailabilityZone, State:State.Name, IP:PrivateIpAddress | [0] }' \
      --output text | sed -e 's,ENVID,,g' -e 's,ENVLAYER,,g' -e 's,NAME,,g' | tr '\t' '\n' | sed -e '/^$/d' | awk '{ORS=NR%8?", ":"\n";print}'

Comment: I am using above command, getting None for IP:PrivateIpAddress in my output >> "ca-central-1a, i-xyz, None, running, r5.xlarge, 800, ABC, XYZ800" .......... @Brad Giaccio please could let me know what's wrong here why it's not showing PrivateIpAddress

Comment: Note I am running this command inside Jenkins and Ansible pipeline so this output is displayed in Jenkins console output

Comment: You want `Ip:PrivateIpAddress` vice `IP`

Answer (score 9):

The below command would list the IP addresses of all your running EC2 instances

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | grep PublicIpAddress | grep -o -P "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+" | grep -v '^10\.'
```

Hope that answers your query...

But this works without all the errors about access:

```
wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4/|grep .
```

Comment: I just tried the same command today 10/23/15 and it works perfectly fine without any problems. What is the error that you see ?

Comment: Grep works differently on OSX which has the BSD version of grep vs GNU found mostly on other standard Linux distributions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413494/does-grep-work-differently-on-osx

Answer (score 6):

You can use [instance metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval) so you can run the following command from the ec2 instance:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

and it will give you the public IP of the instance. If you want the private IP, you will run

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4
```

Comment: This is great! However, I suggest using `wget -qO -` instead of `curl` (even though I use curl 99.9% or the time in my scripts. The reason is that `curl` will output the content of the 404 page if the server doesn't have a public IP, and `wget` does not. So in bash it's simple to do `public_ip="$(wget -qO - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4)"` and get expected results. You can then test with `if [[ -n $public_ip ]]; then echo "Public IP: $public_ip"; fi`

Answer (score 5):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[][PublicIpAddress]"
```

Refer:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html