# How to get a list of all instances and a specific tag in AWS cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Does anyone know how to export all instances in an AWS account with their names and a specific tag?  The tag I have is named Billing by Role.  Trying to get this working with aws ec2 describe-instances.

I tried using this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[] | [0], [Tags[?Key==`Billing by Role`].Value[]]' --output text
```

but I get an error:

ValueError: Bad value for --query Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[] | [0], [Tags[?Key==`Billing by Role`].Value[]]: Invalid token.: Parse error at column 101 near token "" (EOF) for expression:
"Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[] | [0], [Tags[?Key==`Billing by Role`].Value[]]"

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to list all instances with the "Billing by Role" tag that has a specific value? Or just all instances that have that tag regardless of value?

Comment: You already asked almost exactly the same question two years ago. From your previous question and answer you should be able to figure this out on your own. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858864/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-public-ips-and-their-instance-names-on-amazon-ec2/25859315#25859315

Comment: I'm trying to get a list of the names of all our instances along with their billing by role values on a corresponding column.

Answer (score 10):

Got it working with this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{Name: Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0], Role: Tags[?Key==`Billing by Role`].Value | [0]}' --output text
```

Answer (score 6):

This command lists all instances in a region that have a tag named "Billing by Role". Replace the `*` with a specific value to only get those instances with a specific value.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter "Name=tag:Billing by Role,Values=*"
```

Comment: This gives me too much information on the instance.  I just need the name of the instance, and the value of the "billing by role" tag.  For example: mysqldb1.abc.com databaseserver

Comment: Then use the --query option to control the output.

Comment: I used this a year ago: 'aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[] | [0], Placement.AvailabilityZone,InstanceType,State.Name]' --output text', but what's the syntax for gettting the tag values?  Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Billing by Role`].Value[] | [0] again?

Answer (score 3):

To round out [Mark B](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162425/xyz)'s answer and fully answer your question, you can combine both `--query` and `--filter`. The difference is filter is done server side, and query is done client side. If you have a lot of instances, it makes sense to avoid returning lots of data you're going to hide with `--query`.

If you *only* want instances where the `Billing by Role` tag is set, but want to return `"Name   Role"` for each of them, you can use:

```bash
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter "Name=tag:Billing by Role,Values=*" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{Name: Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0], Role: Tags[?Key==`Billing by Role`].Value | [0]}' --output text
```

ORing each property to `[0]` is a nice trick for doing something like a full outer join, it makes less sense with a server-side filter but is nice when you can't guarantee which tag keys are set:

```bash
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{Foo: Tags[?Key==`foo`].Value | [0], Bar: Tags[?Key==`bar`].Value | [0]}' --output table

| Foo  | Bar  |
|------|------|
| None | blue |
| red  | None |
| None | None |
| pink | grey |
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same use case to pull instance-id and name details using a particular "tag project"

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter "Name=tag:project,Values=test-project" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{Instance:InstanceId,Name: Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0],Tags: Tags[?Key==`project`].Value | [0]}' --output table
```

--filter = Specify the required tags Name=tag:,Values=<tag-value"

--query = query to use in filtering the response data.
here we query instance-id, Name, tags