# How do I capture the IP address of a CLI-started EC2 instance for subsequent use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I frequently need to start AWS EC2 instances to work with from the command line to work with over SSH, and would like to write a short script to do this, but I'm stuck at the most basic steps.

For example, I can get started with

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-84Sd8jdf
```

and would like to continue by grabbing the IP address assigned to the instance and using it as an environment variable or script variable to preform subsequent operations such as

```
ssh ubuntu@<theIP>
```

or

```
scp ubuntu@<theIP>:~/soruce_stuff/* ~/dest_folder/
```

but I can't figure out how to get the IP address from the `start-instances` command, or from any of the JSON emitted by other commands.

How do I script starting of EC2 instances, wearing for the IP to be assigned, and capturing the assigned IP address for subsequent use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List public IP addresses of EC2 instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938971/list-public-ip-addresses-of-ec2-instances). Just call `describe-instances` a short while after your instance has started, following the example in this linked answer.

Comment: @AnthonyNeace: How do I get from the list of IP addresses to (a) the one for the just-launched instance that I can (b) assign to an environment variable (for example)?

Comment: Since you know the instance id, you could use the `--instance-ids` parameter on `describe-instances` to filter down to the result for your single instance, and then use the query string from that answer to filter down to the single address that you're after.

Comment: @AnthonyNeace: Nice! This isn't quite a dup of the linked question; so I'd take that as the answer (esp. if it additionally showed how to pipe or whatever to an env variable and/or script variable). And even better: if there was a way to make the script wait until the IP address was available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon offers wait condition to wait for the instance to be ready before you can perform other tasks on it. Here is an example might help you

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids $instance_id
aws ec2 wait instance-running --instance-ids $instance_id
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $instance_id --output text|grep ASSOCIATION |awk '{print $3}'|head -1
```

Answer (score 6):

An example (based on this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24939787/775544)) in bash where the instance is started, the script sleeps (specified in *seconds*), and the public ip address is saved to a local variable:

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-aaaa1111
sleep 10
ec2Address=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-aaaa1111 --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress" --output=text)
```

To verify:

```
echo $ec2Address
11.1.111.111
```