# Is there any way to redirect part of output to a file?

Tags: bash

From the whole output I want to redirect everything between 2 given patterns (or lines)

An example scenario will be, I have a log file and I just want to see the logs printed after a specific pattern until another specific pattern is matched.

Anyone know any way for this to achieve using terminal commands ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does `/the/command | sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p' > /some/file` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep`, `sed` (or any other command that can use a regex) and use `>` to redirect:

```
grep ... > file
```

Comment: If I am right, your command will only redirect the lines matching the given pattern to a file but doesn't work for a range of lines having 2 different patterns. If I am missing anything then please let me know.

Comment: @VivekanandSV That's why I mentioned regex, it can cover ranges.

Comment: Can you give me an example please ?

Comment: @VivekanandSV can you give an example of two patterns you want to capture what in between?

Comment: Start range will be a line starting with "Application Name :-", while the end range will be the line starting with "Conversion Time : -". So i'll need all the lines between these 2 lines including these 2.

Comment: Try `grep -Pzo 'Application Name(\n|.)*(?=Conversion Time)' your_file`

Comment: There is some error as it is showing me the usage details instead of output.  This is what grep -V returned --> "grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD" if that helps. I am on mac btw.

Comment: @VivekanandSV Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413494/does-grep-work-differently-on-osx

Comment: Thanks. For now whjm's answer works for me without any changes from my side, so I'll accept that. Thanks again for your time :)